# while loop to print out only odd numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let number = 0;

while (true) {
    if (number%2 === 0) continue;
    console.log(number);
    number ++;
}
```

I wanted to infinite loop to print out only odd numbers. But this doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: **Run your program by-hand using only a pencil and grid-lined paper**. You should see why immediately (if that doesn't work then I assume you don't understand how the `continue` statement works - in which case you should read this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue

Comment: Q1: what is `number%2`? Q2: what is the condition for `number` to increase? Answer these questions two and a bug shall reveal itself to you.

Comment: `while(true)` will block the main thread. In Node.js, this may work smoothly, but in browsers, this will mostly freeze the UI.

Comment: Sebastian Simon, thanks dude but how come the answer at the bottom works and mine doesn't? They both use while (true)

Comment: Think about when `number++` ever gets called...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's have a brief understanding of the code execution.

When the following code is executed...:

```js
let number = 0;

while (true) {
    if (number%2 === 0) continue;
    console.log(number);
    number ++;
}
```

...the following happens:

1. The first line allocates memory for a variable named number and stores a value of 0.
2. The while loop starts, and it checks whether the condition is true, and yes it is, and always will be, as the condition is simply true.
3. Then, it checks whether the number *mod* 2 returns 0, and definitely, it does, since 0÷2 is 0 and the remainder is 0, so the condition inside the if statement is true, and therefore it executes the code correspondingly. When it sees continue, it jumps back to step 2 and checks the while loop condition, then comes back here, then goes back to step 2, then again comes back here and this never ends(ends when you stop the code execution or close your browser obviously).

Simply put, it never goes forward to the console.log and the number++ line. This is why your code isn't working.

The code from others work because the control actually moves forward in the code and never actually becomes stuck in the above loop.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
let number = 0;

while (true) {
    if (number % 2 != 0)
        console.log(number);
    number ++;
}
```

The code you're using will not work because you defined `number=0` and then you're checking the condition `if(number%2==0) continue;` so this condition will always return true because the number is defined 0 and the `number++` will never increase.

Comment: Explain what you changed and why that fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

```
let number = 0;

while (true){ 
    if (++number % 2 == 1){
        console.log(number);
    }
}
```

no need a `continue` statement, just check the remainder is 1 the print the value in the loop.
you can further shorten the if condition as  `if (++number % 2)`

Comment: Explain what you changed and why that fixes it.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol added a comment

Answer (score 1):

You should increment the number when it is `even` also, to check the next number and so on:

```
      let number = 0;

      while (true) {
         if (number%2 === 0){
            number++;
            continue;
         }
         console.log(number);
         number ++;
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever number is, increment it first. Otherwise, when it is even, it never reaches to number++ any more.

```
let number = 0;

while (true) {
    number ++;
    if (number%2 === 0) continue;
    console.log(number);
}
```